# how to make two classes friend of each other?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class hello;
class demo 
{
private : 
    void fun()
    {
        printf ("Inside fun \n");
    }
public :
    void sun()
    {
        hello hobj;
        hobj.run();
    }
    friend class hello; 
};

class hello
{
private :
    void run ()
    {
        printf("Inside Run \n");
    }
public :
    void gun ()
    {
        demo dobj;
        dobj.fun();
    }
    friend class demo;
};

int main ()
{
    demo dobj1;
    dobj1.sun();
    cout<<"Inside Demo \n";
    hello hobj1;
    hobj1.gun();
    cout<<"Inside hello \n";
    return 0;
}
```

How to make two classes friends of each other ?
i know how to make one class friend of other class but don't know how to make it friend of each other ,i tried separate forward declaration for both the classes still not working ? is it possible to do this ?

it keeps giving me these errors

```
error C2228: left of '.run' must have class/struct/union
error C2079: 'hobj' uses undefined class 'hello'
```

Comment: You already have what you want.  Did you mean to ask about the problem you have with the `sun` function saying that `hobj` has an incomplete type?

Comment: What is the problem, exactly?

Comment: Consider making them the same class if they're that tightly coupled.

Comment: You should implement the `demo::sun` method after `class hello` since it calls the constructor of `hello`. The the constructor should be declared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is in the usage of *incomplete type* here:

```
void sun() {
  hello hobj;
  hobj.run();
}
```

When you're defining the function `sun()` the class `hello` has been declared but *not* defined yet. That's why you cannot use it in a function, and the compiler should give you an error.

In order to solve that problem just define the function `sun()` later, after the definition of `hello` class.

So your class `demo` will be:

```
class hello;

class demo {
 // ...
 public:
  void sun();  // declaration  
  friend class hello;
};

// ...

class hello {
 // ...
};

void demo::sun() {
  // here the implementation and you can use 'hello' instance w/o problem.
  hello hobj;
  hobj.run();
}
```

Comment: To add to @Biagio Festa's answer, this solution can be extended into putting the definitions of each class' member functions in separate source files (one file per class), and each class' definition in its own header (with a forward declaration for the other class before the class definition; `demo.h` forward declares `class hello;`, and `hello.h` forward declares `class demo;`).  Each source file can then `#include` both `demo.h` and `hello.h`, which will result in both classes being complete types in each source file.  This is how more complex projects tend to handle this kind of situation.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with how you set up the classes to be friends of each other but in the fact that you try to create a variable of a incomplete type.  in

```
void sun()
{
    hello hobj;
    hobj.run();
}
```

`hello` is a incomplete type still, so you cannot create a object of that type.  What you need to do is move the member function out of line and declare it after `hello` is defined like

```
class demo 
{
    //...
public :
    void sun();  // <- just a declaration here
    friend class hello; 
};

class hello
{
    //...
};

void demo::sun() // <- definition here
{
    hello hobj;
    hobj.run();
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I've written :)